# Next auth redirect unathenticated users: probelm

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have tried to redirect users using the middleware which seems like the best option.
I am using Next.js latest version and next-auth.
The middleware is in the src/middleware in the same folder with app.

```html
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export async function middleware(request) {

  const token = await getToken({
    req: request,
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    encryption: true,
  });
 
  if (!token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
  }


  if (request.nextUrl.pathname === '/' && token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard/tickets', request.url))
  }
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname === '/' && !token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
  }

  
}


export const config = {
  matcher: '/:path*',
}
```

This is my implementation. I want the user to redirect to the login if he is not authenticated.
I have also tried to get the session in the Page and redirect the user if there is no session.

The problem with both implementations is that before it redirects, it briefly shows the content, something that an unauthorized user should not see.

Finaly this is the [...nextauth]/route

```html
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { compare } from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import connectMongo from '../../../../../server/models/config';
import User from "../../../../../server/models/User";

export const authOptions = {
    session: {
      strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    pages: {
      signIn: '/login',
    },
    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
        credentials: {
          email: {},
          password: {},
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
  
  
          try {
            await connectMongo()
            const user = await User.findOne({ email: credentials.email })
            if (user === null) return;
  
            console.log('user fetched')
            console.log(user)
            let password = user.password
            const match = await compare(credentials.password, password)
  
  
            const accessToken = jwt.sign({
              email: user.email,
              role: user.role,
  
            }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  
  
  
            if (match) {
              return {
                email: user.email,
                name: user.name,
                surname: user.surname,
                role: user.role,
                accessToken: accessToken
              }
            }
  
  
  
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            throw new Error(e)
          }
          return null;
        },
      }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
      async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
  
        return { ...token, ...user };
      },
      async session({ session, token, user }) {
        // console.log(user)
        // console.log('toke')
        // console.log(token)
        session = token;
        return session;
      },
    },
  }

  const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

  export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I guess I could create a component that shows a message to the unauthed user, when the session is null.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Also, should I use the session to achieve what i want, and the jason token only for api validation?

Comment: Normally, if your middleware is working, you shouldn't see the page before redirecting. Are you sure it's working ? Are sure the redirect is not done by the page instead.

Comment: I need to review it again. Would it be bad if I use the Page to redirect. It doesn't feel like a good approach and I have to implement it to every page.

const data = await fetchTickets();
    const  session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    console.log('thing is here we should be able to see the session')
    console.log(session)
   
    if(!session) {
        redirect('/login')
    }

Here even if i do get the session, when I open another window it redirects me to the /login